# Finding which points are closest together (Hand detection)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently able to detect hands when the only blob present is that of the forearm. I simply get a convex hull around the forearm blob, find the depth points of the convexity defects and then draw a minenclosingcircle around the depth points as the hand (since this circle will enclose the palm).

Now I'm trying to detect the hand when the entire arm is present and I'm not sure how to go about it. When I find convexity defects for the whole arm, I will get depth points at the elbow as well and hence a minenclosingcircle will enclose the entire forearm region.

I figured if I could find the depth point that are closest together, i could find a minenclosing circle for those as the palm. This is because the depth points between the fingers of the hand will be closer to each other than those at the elbow.

Does this sound like a good approach? What's the simplest way to find 4-6 points from a set of ~12 points? Any other suggestions will be appreciated as well.

Thanks!

Comment: For that specific case, I would just assume that the palm is roughly circular. So Find and "remove" the fingers like you do at present, then take a circle of diameter equal to the width of the "stump" as your palm position. That way it will work even if the wrist is straight.

Comment: @RogerRowland - I'm not sure I understand what you're saying correctly. Could you please clarify? With my current approach, depth points at the wrist are not a problem since the circle for the palm are expected to enclose depth points between the fingers and the 1 or 2 at the wrist. I have the problem when the whole arm is present in a ~V shape and that causes the circle to enclose the point at the elbow as well, detecting the whole forearm as the hand. I was hoping to eliminate the point at the elbow since that point will be far from the remaining depth points between the fingers

Comment: Ok, perhaps I misunderstood, sorry - I thought you already knew what was hand and what was arm and just need the palm. As you've described it, an arm bent at the elbow is no different to a finger bent at a knuckle, so how do you disambiguate these cases anyway?